# Solving $\sqrt{\left(1+x^2\right)}\le x+m$

Tags: inequality

How can I solve $\sqrt{\left(1+x^2\right)}\le x+m$, knowing that $x$ and $m$ $\in \mathbf{R}$

Comment: You must have $x+m\geq0$ and the inequality between the squares both sides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**

Observe that $$\sqrt{1+x^2}>|x|$$

So
$$\sqrt{1+x^2}<x+m\implies |x|-x<m$$
$$\implies m>0$$

thus if $ m\le 0$, there will be no solution.

Assume that $ m>0$.

$$\sqrt{1+x^2}<x+m \implies$$
$$1+x^2<(x+m)^2\implies$$
$$1-m^2<2mx \implies$$
$$x>\frac{1-m^2}{2m}$$

No we check that $$\frac{1-m^2}{2m}+m>0$$
Finally
$$m\le 0\implies S=\emptyset$$
$$m>0\implies S=(\frac{1-m^2}{2m},+\infty)$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\sqrt{\left(1+x^2\right)}\le x+m \tag{*}
$$
\begin{align}
0 < (*) & \implies  1+x^2 \le (x+m)^2 = x^2 + m^2 +2mx \\
&\iff 1 \le   m^2 +2mx \\
&\iff 1- m^2 \le 2mx \\
&\iff
\begin{cases}
\frac{1- m^2}{2m} \ge x &, m < 0 \overset{(*)}{\implies} 0<\sqrt{\left(1+x^2\right)}\le \frac{1- m^2}{2m}+m = \frac{1+m^2}{2m} <0 \ \\
1 \le 0 &, m=0 \\
\frac{1- m^2}{2m} \le x &, m > 0\\
\end{cases}
\end{align}

Comment: There are no solutions for $m=0$, since $1 \le 0$ is never true.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:
\begin{align}
\sqrt{1+x^2}\le x+m &\iff 1+x^2\le (x+m)^2 \land x+m \ge 0 \\
&\iff 1-m^2\le 2m x \land x+m\ge 0 .
\end{align}